# Setting the bounding box of a sprite in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have three sprites on my scene. I have to make a touch event wherein the player can drag one of the sprites. My problem is these sprites are very thin and whenever I try to drap one of them, the bounding box appear to be very big so even if I touch the empty space and drag, the sprite would move. Here's how I was trying to do it.

```
    NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    loc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

    //Swipe Detection - Beginning point
    beginTouch = location;

    for(int i = 0; i < [objArray count]; i++)
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[objArray objectAtIndex:i];

        CGRect spriteRect = CGRectMake(sprite.position.x - (sprite.contentSize.width/2), sprite.position.y - (sprite.contentSize.height/2), sprite.contentSize.width, sprite.contentSize.height);

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect, location))
    {
        //actions here
    }
}
```

How do I set the bounding box to be exactly the size of the sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    CCSprite * sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite.png"];

    CGRect boundingBox = sprite.boundingBox;
```

However if your image file contains transparent space around your sprite, that will also be part of the bounding box.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, if I set an anchorpoint for the sprite, if the file has transparent space around it, would it still affect the other nearby sprites?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'affecting nearby sprites' but I don't think that changing the anchorpoint changes the sprites bounding box.

Comment: I mean like if I set the anchorpoint and touch that point, would the other sprites nearby it be touched as well?